# Academic Programme of Work for the next 3-5 years

Tags: tenure-track, interview, reference-request

I have an interview for an academic position, and I have been asked to prepare a programme of work for the next 3-5 years. I have googled but I am not certain what sections should this report include. Does it only focus on research? Does it include teaching and research? Please refer a good sample. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For many universities, the expected balance of effort among research/teaching/service is known, possibly published. for teaching universities it might be 20/60/20. For research universities it is much more weighted toward research, but the others are likely > 0. Service can be both inside the university and outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the university and if their focus is more on teaching or research.

For research these plans should include things like:

- What grants you will apply for / when (this is very important)
- What projects will you be working on during the next 3-5 years
- What resources/people/etc will you need any how will you get them?
- How will you build your research group/lab?
- Plans to disseminate your work, in particular outside academia (ie. industrial collaborations, government policy, etc).

For teaching these plans should include things like:

- How will you develop your teaching methods over the next 3-5 years
- Does the university require you to complete any teaching training programs, if so it's worth mentioning this
- Any new courses you would like to develop and how would they fit within the existing curriculum.

You want to make sure it is well thought out, realistic, and achievable at the university in question. Tailor it so that your plans fit with the University's ethos.

If this is a university which works under the tenure system these plans should result in you having a plausible case for tenure at the end. It's difficult to refer to an example since it's highly individual.